# java jButton.doClick() not perform the function (but clicks the button)

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm making a calculator using a textfield to show the results and allowing the user to type the numbers and operations (without clicking buttons). In the textfield I have a problem when the user type something, if it's a valid char i want to do a .doClick() in the corresponding button. I can see the simulated click on the button, but the "cerebro" method is not executed. Where is the problem? Thanks.

This is the code which execute the doClick():

```
    private void campotextoKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    char teclapulsada = evt.getKeyChar();

    switch(teclapulsada){
        case '0': b0.doClick();
                    break;
        case '1': b1.doClick();
                    break;
        case '2': b2.doClick();
                    break;
        case '3': b3.doClick();
                    break;
        case '4': b4.doClick();
                    break;
        case '5': b5.doClick();
                    break;
        case '6': b6.doClick();
                    break;
        case '7': b7.doClick();
                    break;
        case '8': b8.doClick();
                    break;
        case '9': b9.doClick();
                    break;
    }

}
```

And this method make the operations when the user clicks a button:

```
double operando1 = 0;
double operando2 = 0;
char operador = ' ';
private void cerebro(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                         
    javax.swing.JButton botonllamador = new javax.swing.JButton();
    botonllamador = (javax.swing.JButton) evt.getSource();

    try {
        int pulsacion = Integer.parseInt(botonllamador.getText());
        if (pulsacion >= 0 && pulsacion <= 9) {
            if (campotexto.getText().equals("0")) {
                campotexto.setText(botonllamador.getText());
                System.out.println("HOLE 0");
            } else {
                campotexto.setText(campotexto.getText() + botonllamador.getText());
                System.out.println("HOLA 1");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Si pulsas algo que no sea un número
        String operacion = botonllamador.getText();
        //Si ya hay un operador introducido, hacemos la operacion
        if (operacion.equals("CE")) {
            if(operador != ' '){
                int posoperador = campotexto.getText().indexOf(operador);
                campotexto.setText(campotexto.getText().substring(0, posoperador+1));
            }else{
                campotexto.setText("0");
            }
        } else if(operacion.equals("C")) {
            operando1 = 0;
            operador = ' ';
            campotexto.setText("0");
            System.out.println("CAMPOTEXTO ES "+campotexto.getText());
        } else {
            if (operador != ' ') {
                //Si es un operador, buscamos la posicion, substring para el operando 2 y hacemos la operacion
                int posoperador = campotexto.getText().indexOf(operador);
                if (posoperador != (campotexto.getText().length()-1)) {
                    operando2 = Double.parseDouble(campotexto.getText().substring(posoperador + 1));
                    if (operador == '+') {
                        System.out.println("CAMPOTEXTO TIENE "+campotexto.getText());
                        System.out.println("ENTRO EN + Y AHORA CAMPOTEXTO TIENE"+campotexto.getText()+" EL OPERADOR ES "+operador+" OPERACION ES "+operacion);
                        operando1 = operando1 + operando2;
                    } else if (operador == '-') {
                        System.out.println("ENTRO EN - Y AHORA CAMPOTEXTO TIENE"+campotexto.getText()+" EL OPERADOR ES "+operador+" OPERACION ES "+operacion);
                        operando1 = operando1 - operando2;
                    } else if (operador == '*') {
                        System.out.println("ENTRO EN * Y AHORA CAMPOTEXTO TIENE"+campotexto.getText()+" EL OPERADOR ES "+operador+" OPERACION ES "+operacion);
                        operando1 = operando1 * operando2;
                    } else if (operador == '/') {
                        System.out.println("ENTRO EN / Y AHORA CAMPOTEXTO TIENE"+campotexto.getText()+" EL OPERADOR ES "+operador+" OPERACION ES "+operacion);
                        operando1 = operando1 / operando2;
                    } else if (operador == '.'){
                        operando1 = Double.parseDouble(campotexto.getText());
                    }                       

                    if(operacion.charAt(0) == '.'){
                        campotexto.setText(campotexto.getText()+".");
                    }else if (operacion.charAt(0) != '=') {
                        operador = operacion.charAt(0);
                        campotexto.setText(operando1 + operacion);
                        System.out.println("ENTRO EN EL FINAL Y AHORA CAMPOTEXTO TIENE"+campotexto.getText()+" EL OPERADOR ES "+operador+" OPERACION ES "+operacion);
                    } else {

                        campotexto.setText(String.valueOf(operando1).toString());
                        System.out.println("ENTRO EN = Y AHORA CAMPOTEXTO TIENE"+campotexto.getText()+" EL OPERADOR ES "+operador+" OPERACION ES "+operacion);
                        operador = ' ';
                        operando1 = 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //Si es la primera vez que se pulsa un operador
                operador = botonllamador.getText().charAt(0);
                operando1 = Double.parseDouble(campotexto.getText());
                if(operador == '='){
                    operador=' ';
                }else{
                    System.out.println("EN EL ELSE RARO ES "+campotexto.getText());
                    campotexto.setText(campotexto.getText() + operador);
                    System.out.println("FIN DEL ELSE RARO ES "+campotexto.getText());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems you're using the wrong listener. You should better use the `ActionListener` since the `doClick()` might not create a corresponding `MouseEvent` and therefore never notify your listener. Did you verify that your handler is executed at all?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the signature of the second method you already showed. 
Normally it should be part of a class implementing an interface (ActionListener as coding.mof said) or extend a class (like MouseAdapter) and that class should be set to listen for actions on the buttons (with a method like addActionListener).

Comment: hm...sorry but im noob with this. Im using netbeans and the methods were created automatically. The method not have another signature... How can i fix this method? thx